# ValueError when reading a CSV in Python

Tags: python, csv, pycharm, ioexception, valueerror

I have some issues when doing some simple IO tasks in Python and I can't find the solution ... I guess it's something quite simple.

I try to read in a CSV using the csv reader.
First I want to count the number of rows to assign space for the numpy arrays and afterwards I want to read in the actual values.

This method is called within an action method of a button event in a tkinter gui.

I reset the file using the .seek() method but somehow I always get the following error:

***File "...", line 14, in read_csv
    for row in xy:
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.***

I can't figure out what the problem is ...

What's confusing is the fact, that the code runs fine when I run it in debugging mode but it fails when run in normal mode.
I use pyCharm if this matters.

```
import csv
import numpy as np

def read_csv(fileName):

    with open(fileName) as data:

        xy = csv.reader(data, delimiter=',')
        dim = sum(1 for cc in xy)
        x = np.zeros(dim)
        y = np.zeros(dim)
        data.seek(0)
        count = 0
        for row in xy:
            x[count] = row[0]
            y[count] = row[1]
            count = count + 1

    return x,y,count
```

EDIT:

Here's the calling routine:

```
def clicked_ReadCSV():

    filename = "xy.csv"
    x,y,count = read_csv(filename)

##################################

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Test')

f0 = tk.Frame()
lblFile = tk.Label(f0, text = "Enter input-file name with suffix:")
lblFile.pack(side = tk.LEFT)
entryFile = tk.Entry(f0, width = 60)
entryFile.pack(side = tk.LEFT)
bFile = tk.Button(f0, text = "Read File", command = clicked_ReadCSV)
bFile.pack(side = tk.LEFT)
entryFile.focus()
f0.pack()
```

The button action command clicked_ReadCSV calls the above shown routine.

Comment: Can you run it in command lines?

Comment: This is just your function definition. where do you call it and  how?

Comment: @Rebin I edited my post with additional code

Comment: Cannot reproduce with Python 3.6 on Windows. What is the exact Python version and OS?

Comment: The version was Python 3.6 on Mac. 
PyCharm crashed a few minutes ago and after it restarted everything worked ... I guess this was a pyCharm related issue since I can't find any issues with my code